# Java Control Panel doesn't want to save JRE changes?

Tags: java, applet, controlpanel

I'm trying to add some runtime parameters to the Java Plug-In so that I can debug an applet in my browser. I go to the Java ControlPanel, click the Java tab, and click "View..." and add the runtime parameters. After I click OK and close everything, it doesn't work. So I go back to the Java Control Panel, and the changes I just made are gone!

Has anyone else seen this? What's going on? Is this broken?

Answer (score 3):

On Vista with UAC enabled?

- Find the "Command Prompt" in the Start menu.
- **Right** click on it.
- Select "Run as administrator"
- Click "Continue"
- Run `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javacpl.exe` (adjust to wherever you have Java installed)
- Make your changes.

Comment: Sorry, I should've given more information. I'm on Windows 7, UAC is turned off completely.

I found that fix you posted but unfortunately it made no difference.

Comment: This actually worked for me. Extra good because the installed control panel is not the one for the JRE I am using.